# Javascript: Set parameters of an object during recursive traversal?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, traversal

I'm trying to traverse an object and make changes to it.

*I'm able to splice objects that are nested deep within the mother object*

**I'm not able to assign new objects to deep parameters of the mother object**.

I thought that I'd be passing by reference and would be able to make changes to the mother object? (sometimes the object I get is incomplete with respect to the path I need, so I have to change strings to objects to allow traversal to continue)

**Here is the code**:-

```
let obj: any = history.present;
let path = ['the','path',0,'to','the',3,'target'];
for (i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
   if(typeof obj === 'string' && 
Object.keys(manifest.history.present.manifest.assetCatalog).includes(obj)){
   obj = {item: obj}; 
   // this isn't changing the corresponding parameter in history.present
}
   obj = obj[path[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I fixed it. The key was to set the properties downstream a little when I knew they were missing, instead of trying to set them on the object I was examining.

```
let obj: any = history.present;
let path = ['the','path',0,'to','the',3,'target'];
for (i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
  obj = obj[path[i]];
  if(typeof obj === 'string' && Object.keys(assetCatalog).includes(obj)){
    // some code to build out obj's structure to accept the right kind of reassignment when necessary
    obj['new']['structure'] = {item: obj};
  }
}
```